# What DOM event loads images and other components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webview, background, loading

I have a bit of a weird question regarding React and its correlation to loading components triggered via DOM events (updating root container, image src, etc.).

A bit of background, I myself am a mobile dev and for context, I am trying to load a website that is built in react in a webview behind the scenes. When I load this url in the webview in the foreground (app is in the foreground) all html populates just fine. When the webview is in the background however, the image src does not seem to update (I grab the page html and check).

I've noticed this trend of not updating the react root container or app container in the background as well. Truthfully I know very little to nothing about react. With an older web background I suspect (and inspected with tools) JS event listeners on the document and other elements to see if I can manually trigger load events or something to get this working but so far no luck :(

Any guidance would be insanely useful and tremendously appreciated.

Comment: You build you react application into a bundle and that bundle gets loaded, there are several ways to render DOM elements check out https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/rendering-on-the-web

Comment: @0x1ad2 Im aware of that. To clarify my question, I am trying to force render a react app built by someone else. Hopefully that makes sense.